# How to react to network events

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am in the process of writing a Plugin which should react to some data (XML-Format) sent via a socket connection. Since I have never worked with IPC in terms of python before and my knowledge of IPC is, sadly, pretty limited, I'd like to ask you for some ideas and/or help.

So far, my first shot at the problem was to implement a simple non-blocking echo-server inside of QGIS just to have *something* similar running. The code of the echo-server is basically taken from [here](http://pymotw.com/2/select/) and a little modified as follows:

```
def start_listener(self):
    PORT = 10000
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((socket.gethostname(), PORT))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    # Incoming Sockets
    inputs = [server_socket]
    # Outgoing Sockets
    outputs = []

    message_queues = {}
    while 1:
        # "poll" every 0.25 Seconds
        readable, writeable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, [], 0.25)

        # Sockets ready to be read
        for s in readable:

            if s is server_socket:
                client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
                client_socket.setblocking(0)
                inputs.append(client_socket)
                message_queues[client_socket] = Queue.Queue()
            else:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                # if data received
                if data:
                    message_queues[s].put(data)
                    if s not in outputs:
                        outputs.append(s)
                else:
                    if s in outputs:
                        outputs.remove(s)
                        s.close()
                        del message_queues[s]

        # sockets ready to write
        for s in writeable:
            try:
                next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty:
                outputs.remove(s)
            else:
                s.send(next_msg)

        # Sockets in Error-State
        for s in exceptional:
            inputs.remove(s)
            if s in outputs:
                outputs.remove(s)
            s.close()
            del message_queues[s]
```

The Code is launched as a Thread as QGIS will block otherwise. Ultimately the stream contains data which cause QGIS to select given features and pan to those features. My exact question now is: What is the best point of loading such a server? If I'm correct there are two options, namely startup.py or somewhere in the plugin (maybe modify __init__ ?). If I load the server inside the startup.py, is there a way to get a reference to it so that the data can be processed in the plugin-code? Or is there even a better way to solve this problem?

Another problem with the given code is, that it causes a pretty high CPU-load when a connection is handled and the load does not drop after the client has closed the connection.